# Monitor which site is open

Tags: c#

I want to check which web sites is open in browsers ( IE, Firefox, Chrome ) to write a program in C# which can block web site which is in list of forbidden web site. Is there some API of browsers?

Comment: Any browser you are interested in particular or you want a solution that works across all browsers (in this case define *all*)?

Comment: I'm interested in most used browsers

Answer (score 4):

The better solution can be to write a TCP/IP filter, like most firewalls do.

**UPD**: this topic can be relevant: [How do I hook the TCP stack in Windows to sniff and modify packets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695057/how-do-i-hook-the-tcp-stack-in-windows-to-sniff-and-modify-packets)

Answer (score 4):

There is no generic "browser API" that allows access to this kind of information across all browsers.

I'm pretty sure the idea of doing this by accessing the *browsers* is doomed from the start. It is going to be almost impossible to implement, require frequent updates, and always extremely easy to circumvent (there are dozens and dozens of browsers that your program will *not* know.).

The only reliable way is to filter traffic on network level. I would recommend looking into using an existing proxy server or TCP filtering program. There are several Open Source ones that I'm sure you can use as a basis to rewrite or hook into.

Answer (score 0):

The easier solution is to write an http listener that logs the requests.
***Fiddler2*** is one of these, you can check it out. it logs all incomming and outcomming http content.